# c# Jplayer flash

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, sitecore, jplayer

I'm trying to add an Jplayer on my website. I have downloaded it from jplayer.org and followed the guide. It works great on firefox and Chrome, but not on Safari and IE.
Im using Sitecore to add my files (Mp4 and ogv) and adding them to Jplayer.

This is my codebehind where i get the url for the files to add to Jplayer.

```
var Mp4 = (ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["VideoMp4"];
var Ogv = (ImageField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["VideoOgv"];
urlImageMp4 = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(Mp4.MediaItem);
urlImageOgv = MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(Ogv.MediaItem);
```

I have in webconfig changed

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value=".ashx" />
```

to

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />
```

so that the extension from sitecore is correct.

i have an javascript on the ascx file which gets the url and save them in and global variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urlMp4 = "<%= urlImageMp4 %>";
var urlOgv = "<%= urlImageOgv %>";
</script>
```

And in my external javascript file i use these variable

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#jquery_jplayer_2").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4v: urlMp4,
            mp4: urlMp4,
            ogv: urlOgv
        });
    },

    swfPath: "/resources/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp4, ogv, m4v",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_interface_2"
})
.bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function () { // pause other instances of player when current one play
    $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
});
});
```

I have tried to change the swfPath to everything possible (resources is located in the root of the project). But nothing works.
I have tried to add solution: "flash,html". Not working in either browsers.
I have the newest flash installed and i can run the demos on the jplayer.org in my IE9 which uses the flash.

On my site i also have a jquery slider, but it does not seem to cost any problems.

Does anyone have an idea to get flash working and why safari is not working when chrome is?

Comment: Have you tried the JavaScript you posted in a static HTML file (meaning you know that it works outside of Sitecore)?

Comment: how can i do that? I have used the exact same javascript on another page and it work. The only difference is were the swf file is located

Comment: What is the location of the other swf that works?

Comment: it is in a folder called js which lays in the root. And the swfpath is just swfPath="js". But i have tried every possible path.